# R : Date-time Conversion

Tags: r, date, data-conversion

I have in R a date column like this :

`print(d$CREATION_DATE)`

```
"23-NOV-2016 00:00:09" "23-NOV-2016 00:00:23" "23-NOV-2016 00:05:16" "23-NOV-2016 00:05:33" "23-NOV-2016 00:10:26" "23-NOV-2016 00:10:41" "23-NOV-2016 00:15:35"
[8] "23-NOV-2016 00:15:50" "23-NOV-2016 00:20:42" "23-NOV-2016 00:20:59" "23-NOV-2016 00:25:51" "23-NOV-2016 00:26:07" "23-NOV-2016 00:30:59" "23-NOV-2016 00:31:15"
```

I would like to obtain to convert this column in R date format, I tried :

`d$CREATION_DATE <- as.POSIXct(strptime(d$CREATION_DATE,"%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S"))`

but it isn't working, I obtain a NA vector :

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA N
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Run `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")` and try again.

Comment: Thanks ! It's working now !!!